# Oracle 11.2: I need to start a job whenever another job ends even if they reschedule the first job

Tags: oracle

I'm not an Oracle programmer:

I need to start a job I created, to run whenever a job created by someone else finishes.  I'm not allowed to modify their job, and their schedule changes without letting me know.

At first I was thinking that I needed a job chain but am currently thinking it might be able to be done with a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on [Oracle chains](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse009.htm#ADMIN10021). You can define two jobs then define chain that is managing order of jobs execution.

Comment: Yes I looked at Oracle Chains, and was thinking that was the way to go, until I was told that I was not allowed to actually make any changes to the first job.
Looking at my problem I don't think I can do anything other than manually schedule the second job whenever the first job is changed, as I'm in no way allowed to change the first job.